# If $f(x)=f(1/x)$, is it possible for $f'(x)=f'(1/x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = f(\frac{1}{x})$ for all $x \neq0$ and 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = f(0),$$ 
then we say $f$ is an *inverse reflective* function. All inverse reflective functions are completely described on $[-1,1]$, which is the most intriguing feature I can think of.

One example is
$$g(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}.$$

Let
$$D := \{f \mid f\text{ is inverse reflective and $f$ is differetiable everywhere}\}.$$
**Question:** Does there exists a non-constant $f \in D$ such that $f'$ is inverse reflective?

I personally believe the answer is no, but my belief is not based on any mathematical deductions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that

$$f(x)=f(1/x) \implies f'(x)=-\frac1{x^2}f'(1/x) \neq f'(1/x)$$

Comment: @DougM The question asked for non-constant solutions

Comment: Chain Rule...don't know how I overlooked that.

Comment: Yes that is indeed!